# Python returning `<itertools.combinations object at 0x10049b470>` - How can I access this?

Tags: python

I have this simple piece of code that returns what's in the title.  Why doesn't the array simply print?  This is not just an `itertools` issue I've also noticed it for other code where it'll just return the object location.

Here is the code.  I'm running 2.7.1, an enthought distribution (pylab) - using it for class.

```
import itertools

number = [53, 64, 68, 71, 77, 82, 85]

print itertools.combinations(number, 4)
```

Comment: I've tagged your question as 'homework' because you mentioned 'using it for a class' -- let me know if that's actually not true for this particular question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It doesn't print a simple list because the returned object is not a list. Apply the `list` function on it if you really need a list.

```
print list(itertools.combinations(number, 4))
```

---

`itertools.combinations` returns an iterator. An iterator is something that you can apply `for` on. Usually, elements of an iterator is computed as soon as you fetch it, so there is no penalty of copying  all the content to memory, unlike a `list`.

Comment: Is there like a .next() function to get the next element ? without using a for loop, I don't want to copy the whole thing to memory

Comment: @Curious Yes, call `next(c)` where `c` is the combinations iterator.

Comment: Thanks @kennytm, is it correct to assume that I can't access the 10th index unless I call `next` 10 times ?

Comment: @Curious You could use `itertools.islice` to jump to the 10th index (check the `nth` recipe in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
for x in itertools.combinations(number, 4):
   print x
```

Or shorter:

```
results = [x for x in itertools.combinations(number, 4) ]
```

Basically, all of the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module functions return this type of object. The idea is that, rather than computing a list of answers up front, they return an iterable object that 'knows' how to compute the answers, but doesn't do so unless `asked.' This way, there is no significant up front cost for computing elements. See also [this very good introduction to generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 3):

Beside the proposed solutions, other ways, **with a little change to your code**, you can do:

**1)**

```
import itertools

number = [53, 64, 68, 71, 77, 82, 85]

res = itertools.combinations(number, 4)

print(*res)
```

Put the result of the combination into a variable (res), after, with print, use a single asterisks * to unpacks the sequence/collection into positional arguments. More detail is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call).

**2)**

```
import itertools

number = [53, 64, 68, 71, 77, 82, 85]

*res, = itertools.combinations(number, 4)

print(res)
```

This in python 3, it called "[Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)"

A good tutorials about using Asterisks (*, **) in [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/).